# Make error when trying to create *.o

Tags: c, makefile

I'm at my wits end here because of this extremely stupid error I'm getting from my makefile.
I finally gave up stripped the makefile down to just two lines:

```
%.o:    %.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $< -I../inc
```

Command: make . The output:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

The spaces at the beginning are real tabs instead of spaces. The c files are in the same directory. If instead of %.o I give, say, file1.o and file1.c instead of %.c, all is well (file1.o gets created). I see plenty of examples on the 'net that use the % operator, though. If I include a clean: target, it is promptly found, like so:

```
%.o:    %.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $< -I../inc
clean:
        echo "this is clean!"
```

Command: make . The output:

```
echo "this is clean!"
this is clean!
```

Please help me out here as I'm totally clueless about what's wrong with my targets. In the second sample (the one with clean target), I guess the clean target is found and acted upon as the first one is 'invalid' somehow.

Comment: What commands are you typing? (Please edit the post ton contain that information, don't respond to this comment.)

Comment: Look make file tutorial http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: I've been reading that tutorial too, Jayesh. That's where I saw the use of %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Makefile that will enable to any number of targets to compile

```
OBJ :=  file.o

all: $(OBJ)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $< -I../inc
clean:
    echo "this is clean!"
```

Here, **OBJ** will be the list of the files that you want to compile , like here it is file.c

Add the file name you want to compile to OBJ, when make is called it will build the target **all** first which depends on the **OBJ**.

To build **OBJ** the **gcc** command is used.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Appreciate your help, Santosh. :-) Still, a tutorial I found has the following makefile: http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/makefile.3 . This is supposed to work, too, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: #Aashish, yes that would also work, but the above answer is similar to what you have tried, so it would be easy to understand also.

Comment: Yes, Santosh, I get it now. We actually need a *target* (obviously), which is why my original sample was not working (no target!).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to write a target. You have just written rules of how to compile, but not what to do with those objects. I mean, I miss something like:

```
my_executable_file: *.o
    gcc -o my_executable_file *.o
```

**EDIT**:

What is set before is true, you need a **target**. But as you want only to compile, your target should be something like:

```
OBJECTS = file.o #and whatever objects you need, as a list separated by commas
```

And then your target:

```
my_objects: $(OBJECTS)
```

So putting it all together:

```
OBJECTS = file.o #and whatever objects you need, as a list separated by commas
my_objects: $(OBJECTS)
%.o:    %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $< -I../inc
```

Comment: But shouldn't the .o files be created if I'm using -c option alone? I mean, the command works if I just give filenames like file1.o and file1.c.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to compile, not to create an executable nor a library?

Answer (score 0):

When an explicit target is not given to **make**, then the first (non-pattern?) target in the Makefile is used. In the case above, it is the **clean** target.

Answer (score 0):

I see your intention to make only `.o` files (can be needed for creation of libraries).
You can modify your `Makefile` to build **only** `.o` files or build **only** executable by using the same `Makefile`

For the below directory structure (using `tree` command)

```
# tree .
.
|-- include
|   `-- head.h
|-- Makefile
|-- obj
`-- src
    `-- main.c
```

**Makefile**

```
# GNU Makefile #

# Some Variables #
CC := gcc
RM := rm
MV := mv

# Phony Targets #
.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: move

# Path for Source, Object and Include #
SRC_PATH := ./src/
OBJ_PATH := ./obj/
INCLUDE_PATH := ./include/

# Source and Object File Names #
SRC := $(SRC_PATH)main.c
OBJ := $(SRC:c=o)               # Substitutes all SRC but with .c as .o (main.c becomes main.o) #

# Executable Name #
TARGET := exe

# Building Binary - use 'make' #
binary:         $(TARGET) move

$(TARGET):      $(OBJ)
                $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $^

# Building only Object Files - use 'make object_only' #
object_only :   $(OBJ) move

$(OBJ):         $(SRC)
                $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I $(INCLUDE_PATH)

# This rule is for moving .o files to ./obj directory (More Organised) #
move:           
                $(MV) $(SRC_PATH)*.o  $(OBJ_PATH)

# For Cleaning - use 'make clean' #
clean:  
        echo "Cleaning Up!"
        $(RM) -rfv $(TARGET) $(OBJ_PATH)*.o $(SRC_PATH)*.o      # Delete .o and executable #
```

**Execution**:

To build only *object files* use

```
$ make object_only
```

To build *object files* and *executable*, use

```
$ make
```